# Can somebody please analyse this circuit

Tags: transistors, amplifier, audio, analog, analysis

[image]

Can somebody explain to me how this circuit works? i understand that it is an audio amplifier circuit and it inverts the signal, and inverts it again, but i am not sure why this is the case. also ignore the question marks next to some values.

Comment: There are literally whole books written to do that.

Comment: little condescending, but alright.

Comment: I mean, where to start? Do we need to tell you how transistors work? How base bias works? Are you asking about the bizarre emitter DC loading topology for Q1? You've basically left this wide open... like somebody walking up to Feynman and asking "how do magnets work?" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMFPe-DwULM

Comment: Why is it that your the only irate one here? People like you are very detrimental to the community, you assume that everybody should have the same level of knowledge as you, as if to say you were born with knowledge. I know how transistors work, I know what Base bias is. And you're calling the topology  bizzare  because you don't understand it? Please step off your high horse sir.

Comment: My specific beef is that you didn't bother to frame your question with any reasonable specificity. People come on here all the time wanting things explained... people who don't know what a resistor does, much less a transistor. It's difficult to start answering a broad question like "how does this work" when you're not even sure which part is causing the confusion, and there isn't much of a hint to the experience of the asker. On the contrary, I don't expect people to have the same level of experience as I do, but I do expect people to provide full context and a clear question.

Comment: At the end of the day, the only one with a problem is you. Have a nice day, move on with your life.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to what other commentators have suggested, there's nothing wrong with the circuit topology as shown. In fact, it rather cleverly sets the Q point of Q3's collecter at almost exactly 6V, half of the supply voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH1BoJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For the DC analysis, start by calculating the Thevenin equivalent of the bias network: 8.0 V and 16.67 kΩ. This sets the emitter of Q1 at about 7.3 V.

Now, consider R6. Since the voltage across it is limited to 0.7 V, it is carrying at most about 0.15 mA. If we assume for the moment that the contribution of Q3's base is negligible (we'll verify this later), then that same current is flowing through R12, which gives it a voltage drop of 1.5 V, setting the collector voltage of Q3 at about 5.8 V.

This means that R10 is carrying a total current of about 1.23 mA, which means that the remaining current (1.08mA) is flowing through Q3. If Q3 has a gain of 100, then its base current is about 10.8 µA, which is less than 10% of the R6 current, as surmised.

You could iterate through this analysis a few more times to get more exact figures, but that's what circuit simulators are for. I've redrawn the circuit in CircuitLab so that people can play with it.

As far as the AC analysis goes, Q1 by itself has a gain that is set by R6 and R8 to about 21, but since Q3 has no emitter resistor, its voltage gain is very large. Therefore, the overall gain of the circuit is almost entirely controlled by the negative feedback (R12 and R8), which makes it about 46×.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thank you very much. I was looking back at the notes that my lecturer gave me, and this was the circuit that i was provided. I built this circuit over three years ago and wanted to brush up on it. thank you again!

Comment: Yes - I agree to Dave`s description. As an additional point one could remark that we also have DC negative feedback for stabilizing the quiescent working point (via R10, R12). This is important because Q3 has no emitter degeneation (no local feedback).

Answer (score 2):

Very briefly, the general idea is that a positive-going signal on the base of Q1 causes an increase in the current flow from its collector to its emitter.  The Q1 collector current primarily comes from the base of Q3, causing an increase in the collector-emitter current flow of that transistor.  This causes the voltage across R10 to increase, which is taken as the output through capacitor C5 (which is there to block the DC offset of that node).

There's something wrong with the circuit topology, though.  With C2 in series with R8, the only DC path for the Q1 emitter current is through R12 and R10, but R12 is the feedback path from Q3 (note the connection dot under the u in the Out_DC label).  So a quick mental simulation says this isn't going to work.  You might want to go back to the original source of the circuit and check if you copied it correctly, or if the source was reliable.

Comment: Presumably R8 in series with C2 should be replaced by R8 in parallel with C2.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the topology as shown. See my answer.

Comment: @DaveTweed, thanks.  My bad for giving an off-the-cuff answer without thinking it through.  It's easy to fall into the trap of assuming it's someone else's error when you see something you don't expect.  I apologize to one and all.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a two-stage amplifier with dc-coupling and overall negative feedback (R12). The second stage (Q3) - like the first stage - works as a common emitter stage, however, it is realized with a pnp transistor.

This principle is called "DC potential shift with gain". A simple calculation of the bias conditions can show that the collector DC potential of Q3 is BELOW the collector of Q1. In contrary, when both stages would be with npn the collector potential would go up from stage to stage (due to dc coupling).

(Of course, Entropivore`s comment regarding C2 is correct).